# Is there a way to (batch) delete all Subcriptions in Fiware Orion?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Due to some error in a script I have thousands of subscriptions (over 5000). Is there a way to delete them all except by hand?

I know that for entities I can use [this batch delete script](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/utils/delete_entities_by_query.py), however, I could not find out if there is a similar way to delete subscriptions. Is there even a batch mode for CRUD operations regarding subscriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as far as I know, but it should be easy to do with a shell script and curl. Another option is through the mongoDB collection, but that would be a hack that could lead to inconsistencies ...

Comment: Yeah, I used a plain old loop to paginate through the data and remove it. Hoped there was an easier solution.